# accessing XML elements and namespaces from news site with PHP (Edited)

Tags: php, html, xml

I retrieved xml contents with `file_get_contents` and tried `SimpleXMLElement`, but the PHP array I get only holds the parent elements of the XML data.

Here there's my **xml file**:

```
    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9"
    xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/culture/article/2020/03/22/crise-sanitaire-malgre-les-annonces-du-gouvernement-les-intermittents-du-spectacle-restent-inquiets_6034031_3246.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T17:16:47+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T17:16:47+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Crise sanitaire : malgré les annonces du gouvernement, les intermittents du spectacle restent
            inquiets
        </news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>
            https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/20/393/0/4202/2095/1440/720/60/0/b4edd55_cHenKQY0oG4tSBtN-ZWIomUW.jpg
        </image:loc>
        <image:caption>Devant le Palais des festivals, en mai 2019, à Cannes.</image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/climat/article/2020/03/22/l-eau-a-l-epreuve-des-changements-climatiques_6034029_1652612.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T16:34:35+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T16:34:35+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>L’eau à l’épreuve des changements climatiques</news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>
            https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/22/489/0/5300/2650/1440/720/60/0/393a56f_3F3HrswrRMU3J0hrlkkzeI2u.jpg
        </image:loc>
        <image:caption>Une ferme de la région de la Nouvelle-Galles du Sud, le 27 août 2019. L’Australie faisiat
            alors face à une pénurie d’eau sans précédent.
        </image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/journal-blouses-blanches/article/2020/03/22/journal-de-crise-des-blouses-blanches-la-consigne-est-de-se-cacher-quand-le-brancard-passe_6034028_6033712.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T16:02:29+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T16:02:29+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Journal de crise des blouses blanches : « La cot nsigne est de se cacher quand le brancard passe
            »
        </news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/21/0/0/1920/960/1440/720/60/0/47f65f2_MMGpM5CMXMxD42fVNqiTPotG.png
        </image:loc>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/politique/article/2020/03/22/coronavirus-olivier-faure-reclame-une-economie-de-guerre-face-a-l-epidemie_6034027_823448.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T17:23:13+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T15:59:43+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Coronavirus : Olivier Faure réclame une « économie de guerre » face à l’épidémie</news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>
            https://img.lemde.fr/2020/02/19/206/0/5472/2724/1440/720/60/0/46aadf7_ROMWyKxef0RZ6qlNaCNMtbd0.jpg
        </image:loc>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/afrique/article/2020/03/22/guinee-le-referendum-constitutionnel-et-les-legislatives-troubles-par-des-violences_6034026_3212.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T16:19:54+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T15:39:13+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Guinée : le référendum constitutionnel et les législatives troublés par des violences
        </news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/22/460/0/5520/2760/1440/720/60/0/08fb91c_5425067-01-06.jpg
        </image:loc>
        <image:caption>Le président guinéen Alpha Condé s’adresse aux médias après avoir voté dans un bureau de vote
            de Conakry, le 22 mars 2020.
        </image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/culture/article/2020/03/22/suzanne-clement-actrice-canadienne-le-quebec-a-une-forte-tradition-de-series-et-feuilletons_6034025_3246.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T15:37:49+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T15:37:49+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Suzanne Clément, actrice canadienne : « Le Québec a une forte tradition de séries et feuilletons
            »
        </news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>
            https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/21/327/0/5568/2784/1440/720/60/0/0f70086_vXaG6yltE5iz4VrDF2qDMpN9.jpg
        </image:loc>
        <image:caption>L’actrice canadienne Suzanne Clément, lors de la 71e édition du Festival de Cannes, le 8 mai
            2018.
        </image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/sport/article/2020/03/22/coronavirus-le-sport-francais-cherche-comment-dire-qu-il-souhaite-un-report-des-jeux-olympiques_6034024_3242.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T17:29:21+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T15:33:22+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Coronavirus : le sport français cherche comment exprimer son souhait d’un report des JO
        </news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>
            https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/19/337/0/3353/1676/1440/720/60/0/784f910_GGGTOK607_HEALTH-CORONAVIRUS-OLYMPICS_0319_11.JPG
        </image:loc>
        <image:caption>Plusieurs férédations sportives de poids, comme celles de natation et d’athlétisme aux
            Etats-Unis, ont fait comprendre, en fin de semaine, qu’elles sont favorables à un report des Jeux
            olympiques, prévus à Tokyo fin juillet.
        </image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/societe/article/2020/03/22/accueil-des-enfants-de-soignants-a-l-ecole-c-est-une-demarche-de-solidarite-naturelle_6034022_3224.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T16:56:53+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T14:41:08+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Accueil des enfants de soignants à l’école : « C’est une démarche de solidarité naturelle »
        </news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>
            https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/22/0/0/4777/2385/1440/720/60/0/56cd31e_ARMSQexiyfWI90xGw-jwcXzD.jpg
        </image:loc>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/international/article/2020/03/22/au-mexique-l-etonnante-decontraction-du-president-amlo-face-au-coronavirus_6034020_3210.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T16:34:14+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T14:01:41+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Au Mexique, l’étonnante décontraction du président « AMLO » face au coronavirus</news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>
            https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/22/760/0/4854/2427/1440/720/60/0/60b999d_gHeZ41lEmcUNmLcMt2nLBpxK.jpg
        </image:loc>
        <image:caption>Les espaces publics sont désinfectés pour éviter la propagation du nouveau coronavirus, à
            Guadalajara, au Mexique, le 20 mars.
        </image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/afrique/article/2020/03/22/coronavirus-l-epidemie-avance-en-afrique-subsaharienne-en-nombre-de-malades-et-de-pays-touches_6034018_3212.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T12:53:21+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T12:43:06+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Coronavirus : l’épidémie avance en Afrique subsaharienne, en nombre de malades et de pays
            touchés
        </news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>
            https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/20/354/0/4512/2256/1440/720/60/0/ed44517_a34966929416464f9ed860d712a256cb-a34966929416464f9ed860d712a256cb-0.jpg
        </image:loc>
        <image:caption>Vendredi 20 mars, un marché de Lagos, au Nigeria (AP Photo/Sunday Alamba)</image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/politique/video/2020/03/22/suivez-en-direct-l-emission-questions-politiques-avec-jean-luc-melenchon_6034017_823448.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T12:24:15+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T12:22:12+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Suivez en direct l’émission « Questions politiques » avec Jean-Luc Mélenchon</news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/19/19/0/3125/1558/1440/720/60/0/c009a38_5412424-01-06.jpg
        </image:loc>
        <image:caption>Jean-Luc Melenchon, à l’Assemblée nationale, le 19 mars 2020.</image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/m-styles/article/2020/03/22/en-mode-confines-la-robe-de-chambre-en-soie_6034015_4497319.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T12:00:11+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T12:00:11+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>En mode confinés : la robe de chambre en soie</news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/17/16/0/1165/581/1440/720/60/0/945e5b5_21105_3164207.jpg</image:loc>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/culture/article/2020/03/22/barbara-sans-fard-ni-artifice-sur-arte_6034014_3246.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T12:00:10+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T12:00:10+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Barbara, sans fard ni artifice, sur Arte</news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>
            https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/19/15/0/1015/506/1440/720/60/0/1b14c97_n2Y7VWFo3GtyGRr8CX-HiVfm.jpg
        </image:loc>
        <image:caption>Image d’archives de Barbara.</image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/sante/video/2020/03/22/coronavirus-y-a-t-il-un-risque-prochain-de-penurie-alimentaire_6034013_1651302.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T13:39:27+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T11:42:59+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Coronavirus : y a-t-il un risque prochain de pénurie alimentaire ?</news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>
            https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/19/651/0/6016/3004/1440/720/60/0/f8b624a_ws7aMabJUOF620MewwcleXfl.jpg
        </image:loc>
        <image:caption>Une employée remplit les rayons d'un intermarché à issy-Les-Moulineaux dans les Hauts de
            Seine avant l'ouverture du magasin, le 18 mars 2020. Le supermarché ouvre exceptionnellement de 8h à
            8h30 uniquement pour les clients de plus de 70 ans, pour répondre aux besoins en plein confinement
            provoqué par l'épidémie de Coronavirus. Lucas Barioulet pour Le Monde
        </image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/societe/article/2020/03/22/bordeaux-et-la-nouvelle-aquitaine-se-preparent-a-un-afflux-de-malades-dans-les-jours-a-venir_6034011_3224.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T12:43:08+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T11:18:25+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Bordeaux et la Nouvelle-Aquitaine se préparent à un « afflux de malades dans les jours à venir
            »
        </news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/21/691/0/4479/2234/1440/720/60/0/ea9540b_5422352-01-06.jpg
        </image:loc>
        <image:caption>A Bordeaux, le 21 mars.</image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/idees/article/2020/03/22/relocaliser-n-est-plus-une-option-mais-une-condition-de-survie-de-nos-systemes-economiques-et-sociaux_6034010_3232.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T11:00:10+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T11:00:10+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>« Relocaliser n’est plus une option mais une condition de survie de nos systèmes économiques et
            sociaux »
        </news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>
            https://img.lemde.fr/2019/10/11/467/0/5604/2802/1440/720/60/0/3d0a809_xi_Egc7JVMq5WVCdS6uuN0xD.jpg
        </image:loc>
        <image:caption>« Dans l’industrie pharmaceutique () 80 % des principes actifs des médicaments sont importés
            de Chine et d’Inde, contre 20 % il y a trente ans ». Photo : Le port de Busan (Corée du Sud) avec des
            conteneurs.
        </image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/afrique/article/2020/03/22/hubert-velud-quand-je-raconte-a-mes-joueurs-soudanais-ce-qui-se-passe-en-france-ils-ne-me-croient-pas_6034008_3212.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T16:55:29+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T10:00:12+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Hubert Velud : « Quand je raconte à mes joueurs soudanais ce qui se passe en France, ils ne me
            croient pas »
        </news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>
            https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/20/432/0/5184/2592/1440/720/60/0/5c6414a_cYb4lG5ubRKVAZ3WTX7s9gFY.jpg
        </image:loc>
        <image:caption>L’entraîneur français Hubert Velud avec les Crocodiles du Nil, l’quipe nationale du Soudan,
            le 18 février 2020 à Khartoum.
        </image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/international/article/2020/03/22/croatie-un-seisme-frappe-zagreb-et-fait-d-importants-degats-materiels_6034007_3210.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T09:13:31+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T09:13:31+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Croatie : un séisme frappe Zagreb et fait d’importants dégâts matériels</news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>
            https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/22/301/0/3500/1750/1440/720/60/0/f6a5ffa_GDN_CROATIA-QUAKE-_0322_1L.JPG
        </image:loc>
        <image:caption>A Zagreb, dimanche 22 mars 2020.</image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/afrique/article/2020/03/22/face-au-coronavirus-les-puissantes-eglises-sud-africaines-tentent-de-s-adapter_6034006_3212.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T09:00:10+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T09:00:10+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Face au coronavirus, les puissantes églises sud-africaines tentent de s’adapter</news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>
            https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/20/335/0/4000/1997/1440/720/60/0/1617a7d_iyMMTyyOX3k4YG6X6N-YP2tp.jpg
        </image:loc>
        <image:caption>Des fidèles de la Nala Mandate Church prient pour freiner la propagation du coronavirus, à
            Durban, en Afrique du Sud, le 19 mars 2020.
        </image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/idees/article/2020/03/22/coronavirus-cela-n-arrive-qu-aux-autres-aux-pauvres-aux-consommateurs-de-chauve-souris-et-autres-animaux-degoutants_6034005_3232.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T09:00:09+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T09:00:09+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Coronavirus : « Cela n’arrive qu’aux autres, aux pauvres, aux consommateurs de chauve-souris et
            autres animaux dégoûtants »
        </news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>
            https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/17/466/0/3500/1750/1440/720/60/0/552ef32_FW1_HEALTH-CORONAVIRUS-VIETNAM-VISA_0317_11.JPG
        </image:loc>
        <image:caption>« Il n’y a pénurie ni de gel, ni de masques » (Touristes étrangers à Hanoï, le 17 mars).
        </image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/actualite-medias/article/2020/03/22/france-culture-se-mobilise-pour-aider-eleves-et-etudiants-confines_6034004_3236.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T13:19:23+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T08:59:57+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>France Culture se mobilise pour aider élèves et étudiants confinés</news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>https://img.lemde.fr/2015/08/25/301/0/3496/1748/1440/720/60/0/ce6ea9d_15687-e7o6qo.jpg
        </image:loc>
        <image:caption>La Maison de la radio, ici en juin 2014.</image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/international/article/2020/03/22/vivre-l-epidemie-en-etant-expatrie-c-est-prendre-de-plein-fouet-la-distance_6034002_3210.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T08:09:07+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T08:09:07+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>« Vivre l’épidémie en étant expatrié, c’est prendre de plein fouet la distance »</news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/20/416/0/4992/2496/1440/720/60/0/720a12d_5417617-01-06.jpg
        </image:loc>
        <image:caption>A Paris, le 20 mars.</image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/livres/article/2020/03/22/etre-ecrivain-en-inde-un-metier-a-risques_6034001_3260.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T08:00:16+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T08:00:16+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Etre écrivain en Inde, un métier à risques</news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>
            https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/18/398/0/4777/2388/1440/720/60/0/414c7d0_7WW6XOMF3lrYvmp6YYGhoM6R.jpg
        </image:loc>
        <image:caption>A Yavatmal, Maharashtra, en Inde. Sur l’affiche centrale, le portrait de Bhimrao Ramji
            ­Ambedkar (1891-1956), leader ­dalit dont les livres font toujours autorité et scandale en Inde
            aujourd’hui.
        </image:caption>
    </image:image>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>
        https://www.lemonde.fr/critique-litteraire/article/2020/03/22/romans-de-l-inde-bibhouti-bhoushan-banerji-manu-joseph-meena-kandasamy-jeet-thayil_6034000_5473203.html
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2020-03-22T08:00:15+01:00</lastmod>
    <news:news>
        <news:publication_date>2020-03-22T08:00:15+01:00</news:publication_date>
        <news:title>Romans de l’Inde : Bibhouti Bhoushan Banerji, Manu Joseph, Meena Kandasamy, Jeet Thayil…
        </news:title>
        <news:publication>
            <news:name>Le Monde</news:name>
            <news:language>fr</news:language>
        </news:publication>
    </news:news>
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>
            https://img.lemde.fr/2020/03/19/1603/0/1670/835/1440/720/60/0/6bf7fb2_tbnRrg7D2YL_LkrkhPG00Qsa.jpg
        </image:loc>
    </image:image>
</url>
```

While using `simplexml_load_string` I get this **PHP array**:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [url] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [loc] => https://www.lemonde.fr/culture/article/2020/03/22/crise-sanitaire-malgre-les-annonces-du-gouvernement-les-intermittents-du-spectacle-restent-inquiets_6034031_3246.html
                    [lastmod] => 2020-03-12T20:00:12+01:00
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [loc] => https://www.lemonde.fr/climat/article/2020/03/22/l-eau-a-l-epreuve-des-changements-climatiques_6034029_1652612.html
                    [lastmod] => 2020-03-22T16:34:35+01:00<
                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [loc] => https://www.lemonde.fr/journal-blouses-blanches/article/2020/03/22/journal-de-crise-des-blouses-blanches-la-consigne-est-de-se-cacher-quand-le-brancard-passe_6034028_6033712.html
                    [lastmod] => 2020-03-22T16:02:29+01:00
                )
```

I need to retrieve specific element, so how can I gain access to them?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I found a way to get to namespaces elements, but my code is runing in loop, retrieving tens of thousands of elements instead of about 200.
It looks like a problem with the incrementation and the URL (loc). 
I tried to debugg but I clearly lack method as a beginner. 
Here is my code. Could anyone point me in the right direction to solve this bug?

```
        $xmldataNews = simplexml_load_file('https://www.lemonde.fr/sitemap_news.xml');                     //  Load XML data
        $nameSpace = $xmldataNews->getNamespaces(true); // URI namespaces
        $nombreNews = $xmldataNews->count();
        $urls = $xmldataNews->url;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $nombreNews; $i++) {
            foreach ($urls as $url) {
                $news = ($url->children($nameSpace['news']))->news;   //  Get news name of the tag <news:name>
                $pubDateRaw = ($url->children($nameSpace['news']))->news->publication_date;  // Get the publication date of the news of the tag <news:publication_date>
                $datefr = date_create($pubDateRaw);  // date creation
                echo '<tr><td><a href="'.$url->loc.'" target="_blank">'.$news->title.'</td><td>'.date_format($datefr, "d/m/Y H:i:s").'</td></tr>';  // Display
            }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A senior code teacher of mine came up with this short and efficient solution, assuming that any sorting before of the output should be done with , let's say, js.

thanks to @Joffrey-Schmitz for his approach with `Xpath` (scroll up a bit to see it), which worked well too.

If someone happen to know how to do implement sorting of the output in PHP 
I would be very interested and gratefull!

```
    $xml = 'https://www.lemonde.fr/sitemap_news.xml';
    $xmldataNews = simplexml_load_file($xml);  // Load XML 
    $nameSpace = $xmldataNews->getNamespaces(true);          // namespace URI 
    $nombreNews = $xmldataNews->count();     // count elements in xml
    for ($i = 0; $i < $nombreNews; $i++) {  // increment conditions with elements count as limit
        foreach ($xmldataNews->url[$i]->children($nameSpace['news']) as $element)      // looping thru <url>/<news:news>/ elements, increment on <url>
            $datefr = new DateTime($element->publication_date);  // date representation (date format is donne inside echo
            echo '<tr><td><a href="'.$xmldataNews->url[$i]->loc.'" target="_blank">'.$element->title.'</td><td>'.date_format($datefr, "d/m/Y H:i:s").'</td></tr>';  // Display
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use XPath to travel into the document :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('s', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'); // xpath need to have an 'alias' to query the anonymous namespace

$urls = $xml->xpath('//s:url'); // retrieve all url items

foreach($urls as $url) // loop over each url item
{
    $url->registerXPathNamespace('s', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9');

    // string conversion gives you only the content of the node
    $title = (string) $url->xpath('news:news/news:title')[0];
    $loc = (string) $url->xpath('s:loc')[0];
    $lastmod = (string) $url->xpath('s:lastmod')[0];
    $pubDate = (string) $url->xpath('news:news/news:publication_date')[0] ;

    echo $title . PHP_EOL; 
    echo $loc . PHP_EOL ; 
    echo $lastmod . PHP_EOL ; 
    echo $pubDate . PHP_EOL; 
}
```

`//` means that you look all nodes with that name, wherever in the document, and single `/` means that you look at the direct childs of the node. You can read the documentation of XPath to have more commands.

XPath returns you a collection of nodes, so I always query the first element with `[0]` (assuming there is only one such element in your document)

Comment: Thank you very much @Joffrey-Schmitz, I didn't know about Xpath! 
I'm implementing your method.

Comment: It's working perfectly for the first news of the XML online file I gave as an example in the first part of my question, but I've trouble to loop through the rest of the file, which holds almost 300 news. Plus, editing suggestions converted "here is a glimpse of my xml file" to "here is my xml file". My english and giving only one news as example was confusing, sorry for that. So, I edited my question and pasted a good portion of the XML file instead of the first news only. Do you happen to know how to get the needed elements from the entire XML, assuming there are 300+ news?

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly to your new example. Basically, there is a first xpath call to query all the url items, then you can loop on all items and use xpath again in each item to retrieve the information you want.